# langchain: how to use a custom embedding model locally?

Tags: langchain, large-language-model, py-langchain, chromadb

I am trying to use a custom embedding model in Langchain with chromaDB. I can't seem to find a way to use the base embedding class without having to use some other provider (like OpenAIEmbeddings or HuggingFaceEmbeddings). Am I missing something?

On the Langchain page it says that the base Embeddings class in LangChain provides two methods: one for embedding documents and one for embedding a query. so I figured there must be a way to create another class on top of this class and overwrite/implement those methods with our own methods. But how do I do that?

I tried to somehow use the base embeddings class but am unable to create a new embedding object/class on top of it.

Answer (score 3):

```
from langchain.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings


modelPath = "BAAI/bge-large-en-v1.5"

# Create a dictionary with model configuration options, specifying to use the CPU for computations
model_kwargs = {'device':'cpu'}
```

#if using apple m1/m2 -> use device : mps (this will use apple metal)

```
# Create a dictionary with encoding options, specifically setting 'normalize_embeddings' to False
encode_kwargs = {'normalize_embeddings': True}

# Initialize an instance of HuggingFaceEmbeddings with the specified parameters
embeddings = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(
    model_name=modelPath,     # Provide the pre-trained model's path
    model_kwargs=model_kwargs, # Pass the model configuration options
    encode_kwargs=encode_kwargs # Pass the encoding options
)
```

This is how you could use it locally. it will download the model one time. Then you could go ahead and use.

```
db = Chroma.from_documents(texts, embedding=embeddings)
retriever = db.as_retriever(
    search_type="mmr",  # Also test "similarity"
    search_kwargs={"k": 20},
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own class and implement the methods such as. If you strictly adhere to typing you can do `from langchain_core.embeddings import Embeddings` and implement the abstract methods there. You can find the class implementation [here](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/blob/master/libs/core/langchain_core/embeddings.py).

Below is a small working custom embedding class I used with semantic chunking.

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
from langchain_experimental.text_splitter import SemanticChunker
from typing import List


class MyEmbeddings:
    def __init__(self):
        self.model = SentenceTransformer("sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2")

    def embed_documents(self, texts: List[str]) -> List[List[float]]:
        return [self.model.encode(t).tolist() for t in texts]


embeddings = MyEmbeddings()

splitter = SemanticChunker(embeddings)
```

Comment: This is good, but you also need an embed_query() method, or langchain will complain when you try to use the embeddings for example, to load into a vectordb like Chroma. See below for a more complete answer

Answer (score 1):

When you initially run HuggingFaceEmbeddings, it downloads the model. Subsequent runs don't require an internet connection and run locally depending on the model. An excellent illustration of this is the privateGPT project or this modified version, which allows you to utilize AzureOpenAI.

You can find further information on this at: GitHub - MarvsaiDev/privateGPT.
You can access AzureOpenAI for free by setting up an Azure account.
gtr-t5-large runs locally. This model BAAI/bge-large-en-v1.5 also runs locally but requires GPU.

A few questions also:

Have you had experience working with Python before? I am not sure I want to give you a run down on python but LangChain is using Builder patterns in python.
I'd recommend avoiding LangChain as it tends to be overly complex and slow. Once you've clarified your requirements, it's often more efficient to write the code directly. Nowdays most LLM accpet openAI api. Regarding your question about not using HuggingFaceEmbeddings:

HuggingFaceEmbeddings has proven to be reliable and efficient for local use in my experience.

Comment: "When you initially run HuggingFaceEmbeddings, it downloads the model." => Can you please tell the path where the models are downloaded in the local system?

"Subsequent runs don't require an internet connection and run locally depending on the model" => Is there a list of embedding models that can be run locally?

Comment: @AdityaAswani On my mac it is in the folder ~/.cache/torch/sentence_transformers/BAAI_bge-large-en-v1.5/

Answer (score 0):

Check below code :

```
import chromadb 
from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
from chromadb.config import Settings

class LangchainService:

    def __init__(self, path= './database'):
        self.__model_name = "gpt-3.5-turbo"
        self.__path = path
        self.__persistent_client = 
        chromadb.PersistentClient(path=self.__path, settings= Settings())
        self.__openai_ef = embedding_functions.OpenAIEmbeddingFunction(api_key=OPENAI_API_KEY, model_name="text-embedding-ada-002")


    def get_or_create_document_collection(self, collection_name = "collection_name"):    
        collection = self.__persistent_client.get_or_create_collection(collection_name, embedding_function= self.__openai_ef)
        return collection

langService = LangchainService()
document_collection = langService.get_or_create_document_collection(collecton_name="document_collection")
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use embeddings with something like langchain, you need to include the embed_documents and embed_query methods.  Otherwise, routines such as

Like so...

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
from typing import List

class MyEmbeddings:
        def __init__(self, model):
            self.model = SentenceTransformer(model, trust_remote_code=True)
    
        def embed_documents(self, texts: List[str]) -> List[List[float]]:
            return [self.model.encode(t).tolist() for t in texts]
        
        def embed_query(self, query: str) -> List[float]:
            return self.model.encode([query])

.
.
.

embeddings=MyEmbeddings('your model name')

chromadb = Chroma.from_documents(
    documents=your_docs,
    embedding=embeddings,
)
```

Answer (score -3):

I believe I have some ideas that may help you with using the custom embedding model in Langchain with chromaDB. If I understand correctly, you need to create a new class that re-implements some methods in the base embedding class. I have two suggestions on how to achieve this.

The first method involves using class inheritance in the programming language you are using. You can create a new class that inherits from the base embedding class and override specific methods according to your needs. For example, you can create a new class that inherits from the base class and customizes your user interface.

The second method involves using variable and method overriding in the base class. You can create an object of the base class and override the methods you want to change, then call the other methods in the base class through your new object.

As for how to do this in more detail, it will depend on the programming language you are using and the library that Langchain relies on. It might be best to refer to the Langchain documentation and available examples for further assistance in customizing your embedding.

I hope this helps in general, and if you need more specific assistance for your particular case, please specify the tools and libraries you are using, and I will try to help you better.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).